# how can I print my sql string in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I'm using yii framework for implementing a new project.
I want to see the sql string before it runs on the server.
I already enabled this code in my configuration file but I still get no result

```
array('class'=>'CWebLogRoute',),
```

What should I do exactly to view the sql string when I run a webpage?

Comment: maybe you added that in the wrong place, so please show where exactly within the config you added that line.

Comment: Use this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put this under components in main.php (config):

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        'weblogging'=>array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            'enabled'=>true,
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

then it will show debugging info along with all the sql ran on that page.

Comment: care to accept the answer? so it will benefit others users as well. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make simple logger to log your string to file:

```
$file = fopen("my.log", "a+");
fwrite($file, $logString."\r\n");
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **config/main.php**, after db array add like:

```
'db'  => array(
 //your db array listing
),
//add following
'log' => array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace',
            'categories'=>'system.db.*',
        ),

    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration array has a key for `components`, within that you have to add the `log` component, and within `log` you are supposed to declare the `CWebLogRoute` as a route. You will also have to `preload` the `log` component.

Minimal example (*project-name/protected/config/main.php*):

```
return array(
    // other configurations
    // ...

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'), // this is also necessary

    // ...
    'components'=>array(
        // other components
        // ...

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute'
                ),
                // ... other routes ...    
            )
        ),

        // ...
    )

);
```

Read [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) for more tips on logging.